# Weblogic 12.1.3 issue with storing date

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic

After upgrade from WL 12.1.2 to WL 12.1.3 application start store date with timestamp.

So all previous version store date and automatically truncate time but after upgrade it also save timestamp that break functionality.

Issue reproduce for oracle database. Column have Date type in database.
I try to replace ojdbc driver from WLS 12.1.2 to WLS 12.1.3 and it doesn't have effect (replace jar files in oracle_common/modules folder).

Issue reproduced for raw jdbc connection and sql statetments and EJB entities with annotations too.

Do anyone can advice me what wrong can be here?

> Can you post a couple lines on the timestamps you are seeing and point out what you want? Are you talking about manifest files, the deployments listed in the admin console, database entries, or log files? – 
>   I see it in database that perform select queries and application behaviour is changed.

So application save dates and expect that it would be saved as 21/05/2015 00:00:00 (time is truncated). After upgrade it also stores time as 21/05/2015 05:31:23 for example. Some functionality doesn't expect it and during select do not perform truncating of source date and it create troubles.

I perform some investigation and use source decompilation and seems found root cause.
When ojdbc 11.2 driver is used (WLS 12.1.2) it use following code to init date:

```
public static byte[] toBytes(Date var0, Calendar var1) {
    if(var0 == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        if(var1 == null) {
            var1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        }

        var1.clear();
        var1.setTime(var0);
        byte[] var2 = new byte[7];
        int var3 = var1.get(1);
        if(var1.get(0) == 0) {
            var3 = -var3;
        }

        if(var3 >= -4712 && var3 <= 9999) {
            var2[0] = (byte)(var3 / 100 + 100);
            var2[1] = (byte)(var3 % 100 + 100);
            var2[2] = (byte)(var1.get(2) + 1);
            var2[3] = (byte)var1.get(5);
            var2[4] = 1;
            var2[5] = 1;
            var2[6] = 1;
            return var2;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid year value");
        }
    }
}
```

And for ojdbc driver 12.1 that used in WLS 12.1.3 we have following code:

```
public static byte[] toBytes(Date var0, Calendar var1) {
    if(var0 == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        Calendar var2;
        if(var1 == null) {
            var2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        } else {
            var2 = Calendar.getInstance(var1.getTimeZone());
        }

        var2.clear();
        var2.setTime(var0);
        byte[] var3 = new byte[7];
        int var4 = TIMESTAMP.getOracleYear(var2);
        var3[0] = (byte)(var4 / 100 + 100);
        var3[1] = (byte)(var4 % 100 + 100);
        var3[2] = (byte)(var2.get(2) + 1);
        var3[3] = (byte)var2.get(5);
        var3[4] = (byte)(var2.get(11) + 1);
        var3[5] = (byte)(var2.get(12) + 1);
        var3[6] = (byte)(var2.get(13) + 1);
        return var3;
    }
}
```

So difference in setting 4,5 and 6 bytes is obvious.

Comment: Can you post a couple lines on the timestamps you are seeing and point out what you want? Are you talking about manifest files, the deployments listed in the admin console, database entries, or log files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So issue solved by driver replacement.

Root cause is change setDate method in oracle driver 12+ version that i posted above.

Solve issue also is not obvious. To replace ojdbc6.jar you need:

1. Add to classpath this jar OR replace ojdbc6.jar in existing oracle_common folder.
2. Remove ojdbc7.jar from oracle_common in weblogic because it use be default and declared in weblogic manifests files - so no other way to handle it.